# Typescript map.get return undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I want get `Object` by `key` I have `undefined` each all element.

My Map :

```
nodesMaps : Map<number, Object> = [
{ key: "1", value: Object },
{ key: "2", value: Object },
{ key: "3", value: Object },
]
```

When I want get value of this map :

```
this.nodesMaps.get(1) // return undefined
this.nodesMaps.get("1") // return undefined
```

Comment: `undefined` is a runtime value or a *type* hinted by typescript?

Comment: In my case, had to cast search key in get to number, using +

Answer (score 6, accepted):

below code for me..

```
let map = new Map([
    [ "A", "AA" ],
    [ "B", "BB" ],
    [ "C", "CC" ]
]);

console.log(map.get("A"));
```

check this: https://jsfiddle.net/vipinmpd08/1b68eLdr/91920/

Comment: And If I want fill my map with value. How I can initialize an empty map ?

Comment: let map = new Map();

Comment: Wow ! Why we can't instantiate map with key / value ?

Comment: check same fiddle..i updated with three examples..is it something u r looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

You've messed many things.

1. Even if you declared type `Map`, you assigned an `Array` value.
2. The array was array of objects, not array of arrays with length 2.
   etc.

Valid map creation should look like this:

```js
let nodesMap = new Map([
    [1, 'foo'],
    [2, 'bar'],
    [3, 'baz'],
])
    
 console.log(nodesMap.get(1)) // foo
```

Comment: And If I want fill my map with value. How I can initialize an empty map ?

Comment: "And If I want fill my map with value.": `nodesMap.set(4, 'qwe')` "How I can initialize an empty map": Just like this: `new Map()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign properties on top of the fact they aren't objects, they are arrays, and you need to use `new`.  Your code should look like:

```
// TypeScript
nodesMaps : Map<number, Object> = new Map([
  [ 1, Object ],
  [ 2, Object ],
  [ 3, Object ],
]);
```

[Map Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var nodesMaps = new Map([
  [ 1, "Object 1" ],
  [ 2, "Object 2" ],
  [ 3, "Object 3" ],
]);

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var key = $(this).data('key');
  console.log("key :" + key);
  console.log("value: " + nodesMaps.get(key));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-key="1">1</button>
<button data-key="2">2</button>
<button data-key="3">3</button>
```